# installing programs on a USB ubuntu

Tags: usb

im using ubuntu as means of Recovery on my study
i have a Boot Usb with it 
but is it possable to install a program such as a anti-virus or fixxing tools used to fix data on the Same USB?

Comment: Please make sure that you have done everything to explain your problem and needs as clearly as possible in terms of synonyms and grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ubuntu on a usb pen as a standard installation only if it has persistence. If you just mounted the iso as live cd you can't.

To use persistence follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence)
guide or [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) one